# Angularjs parsing function to templateUrl directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is that possible to parsing `function` to `angularjs` `directive` that return a `templateUrl`? In my case, I have this `directive`

```
.directive('forumForm', function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'C',
        scope : {
            data : '=forum',
        },
        templateUrl : '/templates/forum_form.tpl.html'
    }
});
```

This is my `tempalteUrl`

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.Title" name="nameF" class="form-control" required="" ng-minlength="20" ng-maxlength="100">
<input type="" class="tagsinput" ng-model="data.tagIn" />
<button type="button" ng-click="fn(data)">Submit</button>
```

And, I call that via `class` like this

```
<div class="forumForm" forum="forum"></div>
```

Last, my `controller` have a function called `fn`

```
 $scope.fn = function((){ 
      alert('text') 
 })
```

You can see that I parsing a `forum` variable to my `templateUrl` via `directive`. My problem is, Is that possible to parsing a `function` in that `directive`? So if I create

```
 <div class="forumForm" forum="forum" fn="action(forum)"></div>
```

And if I click the `button` (In my `templateUrl`), It's call a `function` that I have written in `controller`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can [use `&` binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-wraps-other-elements) for this:

> The `&` binding allows a directive to trigger evaluation of an
>   expression in the context of the original scope, at a specific time.
>   Any legal expression is allowed, including an expression which
>   contains a function call. Because of this, `&` bindings are ideal for
>   binding callback functions to directive behaviors.

Example:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function MyCtrl($scope) {
  var ctrl = this;
  
  ctrl.forum = {}
  ctrl.log = log;
    
  function log(data){
    console.log(data);
  }; 
}])
.directive('forumForm', [function () {
        var forumForm = {
          restrict : 'EC',
          scope : {
              data : '=forum',
              fn: '&'
          },
          templateUrl : 'forum_form.tpl.html'
        }
        return forumForm;
}]);
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as $ctrl">  
    <forum-form forum="$ctrl.forum" fn="$ctrl.log(data)"></forum-form>   
  </div>
  
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="forum_form.tpl.html">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.title" />
    <input type="" class="tagsinput" ng-model="data.tagIn" />
    <button type="button" ng-click="fn({data: data})">Submit</button>
  </script>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, can you give me an example? I was new in angular btw

Comment: @AdiSparta check out the example. Hope it helps.

Comment: @AdiSparta accepting the answer would be much appreciated :)